How many missiles does Iran possess that can reach Israel?
Is there any credible information regarding the number of missiles Iran has stockpiled in its underground missile bunkers?
How many missiles does Iran possess that can reach Israel?

Including drones & cruise or just ballistic?

Missiles Launched From Iranian Territory

US Air Force Gen. Kenneth McKenzie told Congress in 2023 that Iran had
“over 3,000” ballistic missiles[.]

Via CNN.
At least some of Iran's ballistic missiles have been proven to have the capacity to reach Israel. One injured a 7 year old Bedouin girl who was near an Israeli airbase in the far south of Israel on April 14, 2024.
Iran and Israel are about 1,725 km apart.

A detailed breakdown of Iran's missile arsenal can be found here. It identifies 25 different kinds of missiles in Iran's arsenal, of which eight have a range sufficient to strike Israel. Two more kinds of missiles in Iran's arsenal have a range of at least 1600 km, which could get close enough if they could be fired from aircraft in the Iranian Air Force in Iraqi airspace, or by a mobile launcher that ventures about 125 km into a thinly populated part of Iraq. This source doesn't break the number of missiles in its arsenal by type, however. It isn't clear if all of the kinds of missiles listed at this link are ballistic missiles, or if some of them are cruise missiles.
The two most recent missile attacks on Iran in 2024 were on April 13-14, 2024 and October 1, 2024. The first involved "around 170 drones, over 30 cruise missiles, and more than 120 ballistic missiles." The second involved about 200 Iranian ballistic missiles.
These attacks certainly didn't exhaust Iran's long range missile supply, so the number is probably at least several hundred. Usually national military forces have more shorter range missiles than longer range missiles, so the number of Iranian missiles that can reach Israel is probably less than 40% of its total supply of 3,000+, so probably less than 1,200.
Another source, linked in a comment by max to this answer, also tends to support an estimate in the same ballpark. One new report estimated that Iran had 400 high precision missiles that could strike Israel left after Iran's ballistic missile attack on Israel on October 1, 2024, which is also in this ballpark.
Iran also has thousands of drones that can reach Israel, which aren't precisely missiles (and are much easier for Israel to intercept), although they are a close substitute for them. Iran has four kinds of armed drones that may have sufficient range to reach Israel from Iran's territory: the Shahed-149 Gaza, the Shahed-136, the Shahed-129, and Mohajer-10. Russia has used about 5,600 Shahed-136 drones that it purchased from Iran in the Ukraine War  so far, and Iran has the capacity to produce 6,000 of them a year.
Missiles Launched By Iran's Navy
Israel is about 1,700 km from the closest point in the Persian Gulf. Israel is about 2,400 km from the Gulf of Aden.
Iran's Navy could launch up to 12 cruise missiles from its submarines that could reach Israel from the Persian Gulf or Gulf of Aden.
Iran's Navy also has another 24 cruise missiles that could be launched from the Red Sea from small surface warships, if it could get those warships close enough within the Red Sea. The Saudi Arabian Navy and U.S. and U.K. naval forces in the Red Sea, however, would probably pose a serious barrier to an Iranian attempt to do so.
Iran's Navy has three Kilo-class submarines which can each launch four land attack cruise missiles with a range of up to 1500 km to 2500 km from the Persian Gulf or from the Gulf of Aden. It also has four Shahid Soleimani class corvettes (i.e. small surface warships), each of which have six cruise missiles with a range of 1000+ km, which might be able to reach Israel, although this would be a stretch. None of Iran's other naval vessels, however, carry missiles with a long enough range to reach Israel from international waters.
Iran's Navy has not historically conducted operations in the Red Sea, but if it could get either its cruise missile equipped Kilo-class submarines or Shahid Soleimani class corvettes far enough into the Red Sea, they could bring their missiles within range of Israel.
Iranian naval deployments to the Eastern Mediterranean Sea seems less likely, as Iran probably couldn't use the Suez Canal to get its warships and submarines there, and Iran's naval ships don't have the range to make the trip around Africa, since Iran doesn't have foreign naval bases where it could resupply its ships and/or submarines with food and fuel in Africa.
Missiles Launched By Iran's Air Force
Iran's Air Force, which includes modern fighter jets (a several different types) that can be supported with Iranian aerial refueling tankers, that could get much closer to Israel if it wanted to risk crossing into Saudi Arabian or Iraqi airspace (and firing missiles through Jordan or Syria), allowing it to use shorter range missiles. It also has 5 P-3 Orion maritime patrol aircraft which have a roughly 2500 km operational range and can carry and launch up to a dozen air to ground missiles with ranges of up to about 140 km, which would also be challenged to get close enough from international airspace.
It isn't clear how many air to ground cruise missiles Iran's Air Force has at its disposal, or what range those missiles would have.
Saudi Arabia, a military ally of the United States at the moment, and a long time adversary of Iran (although China has recently brokered a deescalation of tensions between them) would probably use its own Air Force or air defenses to prevent Iranian aircraft, drones or cruise missiles from crossing its airspace. Saudi Arabia probably doesn't have the military ability to stop a ballistic missile speeding across its airspace at high speeds and altitudes.
Jordan is also no friend of Iran and is a U.S. ally, and has a credible air force and air defenses, so it wouldn't allow Iranian overflights of its air space with manned aircraft, drones, or cruise missiles either (although it doesn't really have the ability to stop a ballistic missile from flying over its air space).
Iraq, with a large Shiite political faction that is sympathetic to Iran, in contrast, might react less aggressively to Iranian military aircraft, drones, or missiles crossing its airspace, if Iraq was clearly not the target. Iraq's Air Force and air defenses are also quite feeble as they were mostly destroyed or exhausted in the Iraq War and subsequent occupation of the country and have only begun to be replaced. The only aircraft in Iraq's Air Force capable of intercepting warplanes are its 32 F-16s  that are part of its 9th Squadron at its Balad Air Base (not all of which are necessary ready to deploy at a moments notice). It appears that Iran's attacks on Israel on both April 13-14, 2024 and October 1, 2024 where launched over Iraqi airspace.

Syria's air defenses and air force are already strained by its ongoing civil war and it doesn't even control all of its territory, so it might have less of a capacity to defend its air space from Iranian aircraft. It hasn't managed to defend itself from Israel fighter aircraft incursions into its air space on multiple occasions in recent years. Syria is also no friend of Israel or the United States and might be persuaded to allow an Iranian overflight of its territory without putting up any military resistance, so long as it wasn't the target of the Iranian air raid.

Based on this: https://missilethreat.csis.org/country/iran/ , Iran possesses Shahab-3 and other variants that have 1300km+ range. They had production capacity of 70/yr in 2008. So around a thousand missiles that could reach Israel would be my guess.

Qualifying the Iranian air force's aircrafts as modern seems fairly aspirational.  Their age in turn will limit how many flight hours their pilots likely get.  It's important not to underestimate one's adversaries, but Iran's real threat is much more likely to come from elsewhere/be asymmetric in nature.

The exact number of Iran's missiles is not known, but there are some speculations. According to one report, Iran has over 3,000 ballistic missiles.

Tehran possesses thousands of ballistic and cruise missiles with
varying ranges, according to a 2021 report from the Missile Threat
Project at the Center for Strategic and International Studies (CSIS).
Exact figures for each type of missile remain unknown. However, in
2023, U.S. Air Force General Kenneth McKenzie informed Congress that
Iran had 'over 3,000' ballistic missiles, according to a report this
year by the Iran Watch website at the Wisconsin Project on Nuclear
Arms Control.

Additionally, following the recent missile attack on Israel, some estimates suggest that
Iran has used a third of its high-precision missiles.
In conclusion, while the exact number of Iran's missiles is uncertain, reports indicate that Iran has over 3,000 ballistic missiles, of which approximately 500 are high-precision missiles, based on the recent missile attack on Israel where advanced missiles were employed.
